# Android : Test network connection in main thread AsyncTask Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm parsing xml on server by using http client...and I want to give condition if the internet is connected or not.

Here is the class testConnection :

```
    public boolean testConnection()
        {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) 
            {
               Log.d("NetWork :", "Network available");
               return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.d("NetWork :", "Network not available");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And my asyncTask class is work fine. and i put condition in onCreate methode in activity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //asyncTask is main thread class that parsing xml from server
    asyncTask task = new asyncTask();
    if(testConnection())
    {
        task.execute();
    }
    else
    {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.airport.testConnection"));
    }

}
```

And the problem is that, when I close the internet connection ( disable wifi ) and open application, it's always crush.

All answer and comment would be appreciated....

Comment: @Priyank : emulator always connect, and I test in phone..... sorry

Comment: `new Intent(this, com.airport.testConnection.class)`

Answer (score 0):

pass context(this) in starting activity